# Is it possible to change the mnemonic seed of a monero wallet?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I was just wondering it was possible to change the mnemonic seed of a monero wallet?

Answer (score 1):

No. I actually had to just double-check, as I wondered if changing the wallet password maybe changed the seed, but it didn't.

If you need a new seed (because your existing one is compromised for example), you'll need to create a new wallet and transfer the funds over.